Azure App Configuration Kubernetes Provider: How do I specify a secondary endpoint for my replica incase of region failure?
I am currently using azure app configuration kubernetes provider and I am able to successfully access the configs via the file that is on the volume attached to my container.
In my App Config Provider I specify the endpoint for my store.  My question is, since I have replicas for my store, in the case of a region failure how do I specify the secondary endpoint so that it will fetch my configs from the replica incase the main store has an outage?  Is there a way to do this with one provider?

We are working on replica auto discovery of Kubernetes provider. For App Configuration stores with geo-replication enabled, the k8s provider will automatically discover any additional replicas and attempt to connect to them when it fails to connect to user-provided endpoint.
It will be supported in the coming release, please stay tuned.

Awesome!  Any ETA on the next release?

We will release the new version within this month.

Do you guys have a page I can follow to see when it is released?

https://github.com/Azure/AppConfiguration/blob/main/releaseNotes/KubernetesProvider.md This is assume?

Yes, it's release notes of Kubernetes provider. And you can also open issues to ask questions or share feedback about Azure App Configuration.

One more question.  I can make a new topic if needed.  When my config maps values are updated, is it possible to restart the deployment containers via the provider?

Hi @JSnoob, Kubernetes provider v1.3.0 has been released, which supports replica auto discovery.
